# Python Pandas conditional sum, while leaving other values in place

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum, pandas-groupby

My df is this:

```
year    state     party         percentage 
1976    Arizona   republican    43.34
1976    Arizona   third party   0.21
1976    Arizona   democrat      54.01
1976    Arizona   third party   0.99
1976    Arizona   third party   .45
1978    Alabama   third party   6.01
1978    Alabama   republican    43.32
1978    Alabama   third party   0.82
1978    Alabama   democrat      55.06 
1978    Alabama   democrat      93.99
1978    Alabama   third party   0.80
```

I want to use `.groupby` but only sum a row if the party is "third party". Here's my code:

```
g = df_senate.groupby(['year','state','party'], as_index=False)
g.apply(lambda x: x[x['party'] == 'third party']['percentage'].sum())
```

It almost works, but I get 0 for the other "party" values, and it rolls up the other parties. I want to keep the additional 'democrat' and 'republican' rows for each year/state un-summed. I only want 'third party' summed:

```
year  state       party          percentage
1976  Arizona     democrat       0.00
                  republican     0.00
                  third party    2.65
1978  Alabama     democrat       0.00
                  republican     0.00
                  third party    7.63
```

Also how do I keep it as a dataframe? Putting `as_index=False` in the `.groupby` didn't work. What I want to end up with is:

```
year  state       party          percentage
1976    Arizona   republican    43.34
1976    Arizona   third party   2.65
1976    Arizona   democrat      54.01
1978    Alabama   third party   7.63
1978    Alabama   republican    43.32
1978    Alabama   democrat      55.06 
1978    Alabama   democrat      93.99
```

(In case you're wondering, this is Senate election data and sometimes a state would have to elect 2 senators, not just one, and I need to not have percents summing to over 100%, because that would be weird)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = (
        df.groupby(['year', 'state', 'party'])['percentage'].apply(
            lambda x: [x.sum()] if x.name[2] == 'third party' else list(x))
        .explode()
        .reset_index() 
      )

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   year    state        party percentage
0  1976  Arizona     democrat      54.01
1  1976  Arizona   republican      43.34
2  1976  Arizona  third party       1.65
3  1978  Alabama     democrat      55.06
4  1978  Alabama     democrat      93.99
5  1978  Alabama   republican      43.32
6  1978  Alabama  third party       7.63
```